# Group consecutive days in Week in MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I want to be able to group a table of sales by week but only by the first x number of days.

I can group by week easily

```
 SELECT SUM( order_total_price ) AS total, WEEK(order_time,1) AS week_number
 FROM orders
 WHERE YEAR( order_time ) = 2014
 GROUP BY WEEK( order_time, 1 )
```

So I want to get the aggregate sum of orders for each day of the week. 
I will need to run this query 7 times for each of the days.

Here is some sample data. I have selected a range of totals from Mon-Sun

```
+-------------+-------------------+  
| order_time  | order_total_price |  
+-------------+-------------------+  
| 2014-03-03  |                20 |  
| 2014-03-04  |                25 |  
| 2014-03-05  |                30 |  
| 2014-03-06  |                15 |  
| 2014-03-07  |                20 |  
| 2014-03-08  |                15 |  
| 2014-03-09  |                30 |  
| 2014-03-10  |                20 |  
| 2014-03-11  |                15 |  
| 2014-03-12  |                10 |  
| 2014-03-13  |                25 |  
| 2014-03-14  |                30 |  
| 2014-03-15  |                25 |  
| 2014-03-16  |                10 |  
+-------------+-------------------+
```

Here is the results that I am after

```
+----------+-------------+-------+   
| end_day  | week_number | total |   
+----------+-------------+-------+   
|        1 |         10  |    20 |  
|        2 |          10 |    45 |  
|        3 |          10 |    75 |  
|        4 |          10 |    90 |  
|        5 |          10 |   110 |  
|        6 |          10 |   125 |  
|        7 |          10 |   155 |  
|        1 |          11 |    20 |  
|        2 |          11 |    35 |   
|        3 |          11 |    45 |  
|        4 |          11 |    70 |  
|        5 |          11 |   100 |  
|        6 |          11 |   125 |  
|        7 |          11 |   135 |   
+----------+-------------+-------+
```

The `end_day(1=Mon - 7=Sun)` would be the day which the aggregate of the week total is calculated to. Notice how the totals are the aggregate total to that day of the week.

Comment: I think I may of not explained myself correctly. I want to group the data by week but group the week by only by x number of days. So I want to group the week by Mon to Tue, then Mon to Wed then Mon to Thu etc Eg So the start of the week is Monday and the week ends of the week is Thursday. Thats why I need to run the query 7 times. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT
    sum(order_total_price) AS total,
    WEEK(order_time,1) AS week_number, date_format(order_time,'%w') as day_of_week
FROM orders
WHERE YEAR(order_time) = 2014
    AND date_format(order_time,'%w') >= 1
    AND date_format(order_time,'%w') <= 2
    -- date_format(date,format)
    -- %w: Day of the week (0=Sunday, 6=Saturday)
GROUP BY WEEK(order_time,1), date_format(order_time, '%w')
```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts! Maybe if i give you an example of what i am trying to explain.

Comment: Not sure what you're looking for, **"but only by the first x number of days"** can be done with a where clause on days. Is this: **"the aggregate sum of orders for each day of the week"** asking to add up all of day 1, for each week, over multiple weeks? Maybe add an example of your expected output.

Comment: I think I may of not explained myself correctly. I want to group the data by week but group the week by only by x number of days. So I want to group the week by Mon to Tue, then Mon to Wed then Mon to Thu etc Eg So the start of the week is Monday and the week ends of the week is Thursday. Thats why I need to run the query 7 times. Hope this helps.

Comment: Check my updated answer. Then look at date_format(), %w is the day of the week, 0 being Sunday. If this is what you're looking for, great. However, next time, please include sample data and desired result. Much easier to answer.

Comment: I have added some sample data and results.

Comment: I guess what I am after is a running total for each week.